# Updating label upon getting message from queue

Tags: python, tkinter, queue, python-multithreading

I'm trying to update the label to display the numbers being counted down when it receives the number through the queue. I am able to see it being printed in the console but the label does not change. Any help or suggestion would be helpful!

Here is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import time
import threading
import queue

class GUIApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.buttonCountDown = tk.Button(text='Count Down', command=self.countDownAction)
        self.buttonCountDown.pack()
        self.label = tk.Label(text='default')
        self.label.pack()
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def countDown(self, seconds):
        for i in range(seconds, 0, -1):
            self.queue.put(i)
            time.sleep(1)

    def listenToQueue(self):
        while True:
            try:
                if self.queue.empty() == False:
                    print(self.queue.get(0))
                    self.label['text'] = self.queue.get(0)
                elif self.queue.empty() == True:
                    pass
            except queue.Empty:
                pass

    def countDownAction(self):
        listenThread = threading.Thread(target=self.listenToQueue)
        listenThread.start()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.countDown, args=(5,))
        thread.start()
        thread.join()

app = GUIApp()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to know is `Queue.get()` removes the item and returns it, similar to `dict.pop()`. So when you do `print(self.queue.get(0))`, the item is already removed from the queue. You have to assign it to a variable first if you want to both print and config it:

```
def listenToQueue(self):
    while True:
        try:
            if self.queue.empty() == False:
                s = self.queue.get(0)
                print (s)
                self.label['text'] = s
            elif self.queue.empty() == True:
                pass
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
```

Next, calling `thread.join()` will wait for the thread terminates. You don't need to call this method at all in your current setup.

```
def countDownAction(self):
    listenThread = threading.Thread(target=self.listenToQueue)
    listenThread.start()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.countDown, args=(5,))
    thread.start()
    #thread.join() #not required
```

Comment: doing that I was able to change the label to 1 but I didn't get to see it count down 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. Am I doing something wrong with the countDown method?

Comment: Did you comment out `thread.join`? I can see countdown to 1 just fine with the above two amended.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't comment it out and yes it works perfectly now. What if I want to do something after the thread is done? Do I have to use thread.join()?

Comment: I would just add whatever needs to be done at the end of your countdown function outside the for loop.

Comment: I see. Is there a way of doing it outside of the countDown function?

Comment: I suppose you can also feed your result to another queue, and have listentoqueue function also check for that queue and act accordingly. It largely depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Got it! I was just curious but thank you that was very helpful!